# Codeigniter input file returns empty to post form with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload a file to the server with l framework CodeIgniter, jQuery ajax, but I submit the form returns empty image field, and the picture is not up.

I appreciate your help please.

Here the code

**Controller:**

```
public function do_upload()
{
    //Check if isset request AJAX
    if( ! $this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
        show_404();
    }

    //Config upload files
    $config = array(
                    'upload_path'   => './assets/files/',
                    'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
                    'max_size'      => '2048 ',
                    'overwrite'     => TRUE,
                    'remove_spaces' => TRUE
                    );

    //Load library
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('imagen') ) {

        $error = array(
                        'respuesta' => FALSE,
                        'message'   => $this->upload->display_errors()
                      );
        echo json_encode( $error );
    }
    else{
        $config = array(
                        'respuesta' => TRUE,
                        'message'   => 'Completado!'
                        );
        echo json_encode( $config );
    }


}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col_right">
<div class="ctn">
  <h3>Subir contenido al servidor</h3>

    <form action="" method="POST" id="form_file" name="form_file" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
        </div>

        <button type="button" id="btn_form" class="btn btn-primary">Subir imagen</button>
    </form>

</div><!--End ctn-->
```

**Script Jquery Ajax:**

```
$(function() {

  $('#btn_form').on('click', function(event) {

    //Serialize form
    var form_serialize = $("#form_file").serialize();
    alert(form_serialize);

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/file/do_upload/",
        data: form_serialize + "&id=" + Math.random(),
        success: function (response) {

            if (response.respuesta == true) {
                alert(response.message);
            }

            if (response.respuesta == false) {
                alert(response.message);
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('SYSTEM ERROR, TRY LATER AGAIN');
        }
    });
  });
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Have to do like this

change the button type to `submit`  ,,

change the jquery function

```
$(function () {
            $('#form_file').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
//                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    //  dataType: "json",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                     url: "/file/do_upload/",
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.respuesta == true) {
                            alert(response.message);
                        }
                        if (response.respuesta == false) {
                            alert(response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('SYSTEM ERROR, TRY LATER AGAIN');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am grateful.

I applied the changes I return a value [object FormData], also I see some options as dataType were annulled.

I think it best to review the entire project to see it work, I uploaded the changes to Dropbox, throughout the entire project, if this is not possible, but the idea is that a real example is shown with full functionality.

Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lg2zt0i4h7kf5jk/practica.zip?dl=0

Link the system to upload images with ajax: http://localhost/upload_ajax